# Why does this javascript code that is supposed to only show results that match typed input filter only the first 10 options?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of code (only a snippet, everything else is css) that as I type shows only the options that match my typed input. But for some reason, it only filters the first 10 options. The rest of the options just show no matter what. Any ideas why?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
a { color: white }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left" style="background-color:#2D2D2D; color: white;">
    <h2>***PAVADINIMAS***</h2>
    <input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Paieška" title="Type in a category">
    <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">abcde</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">monday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tuesday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">wednesday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">thrusday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">friday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">saturday</a>
      <li>
      <li><a href="#">sunday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">iii</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">12345</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">qwerty</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I searched the web but haven't found anything similar to this.

Comment: In the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')",` because your li has an error, you did not close the one

Comment: I edited your question to make it runnable and I formatted it so the error stands out. Get a linter/ beautifier on your IDE so these typos stand out. Look at your developer console since you clearly did not see the error message.

Comment: Thank you both so much, didn't see that, I am so sorry. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extra `<li>` tag is rendered by the browser as an empty `<li>` element (i.e. `<li></li>`). Thus, when it is looped over by your for loop, the following lines fail:

```
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
```

because the empty `li` element doesn't contain an `a` element, and thus the `a` variable is undefined, causing `a.innerHTML` to throw an error (since you can't access a property on an undefined value).

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't see that, I am so sorry. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

While it is valid to not have closing tags on `</li>` sometimes that can challenge code - one reason to never omit on things like `<li>`, `<p>` etc. that allow this
Here I updated to use a closing tab on both those that did not have it.

Out of scope but I also updated the script to account for missing elements that returned undefined (missing the `<a>` for example

```js
function myFunction() {
  let input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (!!a && a.innerHTML != "" && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
a { color: white }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left" style="background-color:#2D2D2D; color: white;">
    <h2>***PAVADINIMAS***</h2>
    <input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Paieška" title="Type in a category">
    <ul id="myMenu">
      <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">abcde</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">monday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tuesday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">wednesday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">thrusday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">friday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">saturday</a>
      </li><li></li>
      <li><a href="#">sunday</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">iii</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">12345</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">qwerty</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```